# Conflicting type attributes specified

Tags: c++

I use libxl with IBookT.h file:

```
namespace libxl {

    template<class TCHAR>
    struct IBookT
    {
        virtual             bool XLAPIENTRY load(const TCHAR* filename) = 0;
        virtual             bool XLAPIENTRY save(const TCHAR* filename) = 0;

        <...>
```

and try to create own child class

```
#include "libxl.h"
template<class TCHAR>
class CSVBook: public libxl::IBookT<TCHAR>
{
    bool load(const TCHAR* filename);
    bool save(const TCHAR* filename);
    <...>
```

This code works fine at linux, but doesn't compile at windows. Compilation ends with error:

```
conflicting type attributes specified for 'bool CSVBook<TCHAR>::load(const TCHAR*) [with TCHAR = char]'
 bool load(const TCHAR* filename);
      ^
```

How I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `XLAPIENTRY` in your method declarations (before `load` and `save`). I suppose it's empty on Linux and expands to something important on Windows.